# Calculus Spivak 3e pg 90: Limit of a function

Tags: calculus

[http://imgur.com/cbFj7B5](https://imgur.com/cbFj7B5)

"Of the six functions graphed in Figure 1, only the first three approach l at a.
Notice that although g(a) is not defined, and h(a) is defined “the wrong way,” it is still true that g and h approach l near a."

Could someone take a look at the image of that page and tell me what he's talking about? What are those weird arrows?

Example: for 'g' he's got two arrows to indicate that the limit approaches 'a' from the left and right side of the x-axis. Okay so at 'a' the limit does not exist so g(a) is not defined BUT in the next plot h(a) is defined but then he babbles about h(a) being defined the 'wrong way' - what does he mean by that?

I'm guessing the 1st horizontal row has valid limits; but why is the 2nd row 1st col, invalid - because there you can approach 'a' from only one direction? But then what's with that weird arrow Spivak's inserted?

Comment: Your highlighted text in the image is just as confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About Spivak's arrows:** Spivak seems to want to stress that the limit of a function $f$ at some argument $a$ is independent from the definition of $f$ at $a$. It can be undefined (has no value at all), or some arbitrary value $f(a)$ at $a$.

The funny arrow drawings as part of a function graph seem to represent two ideas:

1. the idea of a limit as a process that approaches along the body of the arrow towards the point at the tip of the arrow
2. the points on the body of the arrow are part of the function graph, but the point at the tip of the arrow is not part of the function graph

Another way to indicate if a point is part of the function's graph or not is to use open circles (in case the point at the center is excluded) or thick bullet points (to stress that this point is part of the graph). See [this page](http://www.onlinemathe.de/mathe/inhalt/Stetigkeit) for examples of that kind of illustration.

**First row:** The left and right limits of $g$ exist and have the same value $l$. Only the value $g(a)$ does not exist. (The two arrows approach the gap point $(a, l)$ but do not touch it)

Same case for $h$, only that in this case a) $h(a)$ is defined and b) $h(a)$ is different from the two limits towards $a$. $$
\lim_{{x \to a} \atop {x < a}} h(x) =
\lim_{{x \to a} \atop {x > a}} h(x) =
\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = l \ne h(a)
$$

Because $h(a)$ is different from the limit he declares $h$ as defined "the wrong way" at $a$. Don't take "wrong" too serious, it is a mathematical sound act to define $h$ that way, this goes towards the concept of a continous funcion, $h$ is defined to be not continous here. In that sense it is "wrong" because it is not a smooth graph, you can't draw it without pulling your pen from the paper. The "right way" would have been to define $h(a)$ such that it fills the gap nicely.

**Second row, first entry:** Lets call this function $i$, then you have $i(a) = l$ defined and coming from the left: 
$$
\lim_{{x \to a} \atop {x < a}} i(x) = l
$$ 
However if you approach $a$ from the right, that half of the graph with the arrow  points to a value larger than $l$: 
$$
\lim_{{x \to a} \atop {x > a}} i(x) = l + \Delta y
$$ 
with some number $\Delta y > 0$.

So those limits are different, they differ by the value $\Delta y$. We have a gap. So you have two limit values and not one common limit value. The function is not continous at $a$. It jumps.

**Second row, second entry:** That is another interesting case. The left half of the graph approaches $a$ nicely, the limit from the left exists. However for the right half the function oscillates and oscillates faster, as it approaches $a$, the limit from the right does not exist. It might be defined as
$$
j_{a+}(x) = l + \sin \frac{1}{x - a}
$$
So there is no common limit value for all possible approaches towards $a$.

Comment: could you elaborate on how h(a) is defined the 'wrong way'? Is it because you can approach the limit only from 0+ (from the left to right) and not 0- (right to left)

Comment: okay, so the arrows and arrowhead are part of the graph of the function and not an annotation. I thought he was doodling on my graph and found it very confusing.A small correction: 'two arrows would meet at the gap point' they won't meet but they'd come very close, separated by the vacancy at g(a) and by h(a) being offset-downwards.

Comment: 2x3 f(a) has a limit but it's not 'l'

Comment: First, these are all illustrations to help explain the subject. It is doodling. And I would also consider them more to be annotations. It is hard to define a function by an illustration. For example it is not possible to draw a line, where you omit just a single mathematical point, as a mathematical point has no extend, while ink has.

Comment: Yes, regarding row 2, last one, that function is just defined to be different from $l$ at $a$.

Comment: I reworded it and hope that I got it nailed now. :-)